# django - creating a preview page

Tags: django, django-views

i have a 'Add Post' page in my blog app. and i wanna add a 'preview page'. i should click preview button even before save the post. for this ; i ve created two new fields in my models.py which are : titlePreview and bodyPreview.

what i am doin is saving form datas into these two fields to preview the page before publish.

but i couldn't do that. i have a addPost view. here it is :

```
@login_required(login_url='/panel')
def addpost(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        form = addForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            titleform=form.cleaned_data['title']
            bodyform=form.cleaned_data['body']
            checkform=form.cleaned_data['isdraft']
            owner = request.user
            n = Post(title = titleform, body = bodyform, isdraft=checkform, owner=owner)
            n.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/admin/')
    else:
        form=addForm()
        return render(request,'add.html',{'form':form,})
    return render(request,'add.html',{'form':form,})
```

here is my models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    body = models.TextField()
    bodyPreview = models.TextField()
    titlePreview = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title',unique=True)
    posted = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    isdraft = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    @permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('view_blog_post',None, {'postslug':self.slug})
```

now i think i should create a different view like 'preview_view' which must redirects to 'preview.html' from addpost.html.

but i couldnt connect the points.

thank you

Comment: Maybe it is just silly but... What if you simply pass the needed data via POST to the `preview_view`? This way you don't need to save anything in the database.

Comment: how can i do that? can you be more spesific?

Comment: In the "creating page" template when you click the preview button, you send the data via POST as if it were a form. The action it will be `preview_view` URL and this view will get the parameters from POST. Then inside the view you can just call the blog post template or whatever with the proper data.

Comment: i understand you. but i couldnt do it in code. there are 2 views. how can i reach a view's form data from another view ? like request.Post.title and request.POST.body ? if it is ; and then? sorry but it is great if you explain it with codes :)

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation of my previous comments

#### First part: *Creating page* template passes the blog post data via `POST`

This part can be implemented in many ways, this is one with a form:

```
<form action={% url "preview_page" %} method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="title" value="{{ post_title }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="body" value="{{ post_body }}">
    <input type="submit" name="preview_button" value="preview">
</form>
```

#### Second part: Create the view preview_page

```
@login_required(login_url='/panel')
def previewpost(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        # Here pass the POST data to the template, POST is already a dict,
        # so it may be can fit directly into the template if names match
        # though it is always better to check the values first
        return render(request,'post_template.html', request.POST)
    else:
        ...
```

#### post_template.html

```
...
<h1>{{ title }}</h1>
<p>{{ body }}</p>
...
```

Disclaimer: The code is not tested at all

The downside of this solution is that you have to actually pass the data (title, body) again from the client to the server. I hope this works for you.

Comment: when i do this it works but in preview.html seems nothnig. when i click preview button ; it just redirects to preview.html. no data. how can i call the datas from template file? in preview.html

Comment: In the example I'm passing request.POST as template context, so in your template, the vars names must be the same as the names of the hidden form fields.

Comment: it didnt work. there is no error. but didint work. i need to go outside now. thanks for help :)